# Passing a variable to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, function, variables, parameter-passing

I would like to call a JavaScript function from my php page, which looks like this:

**xyz.php**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($temp2a); $i++) {
    $URL = "xyz.php?eingabe=".$temp2a[$i]."&eingabe2=".$datei;
    echo '<p><a href="#" onClick="test("'.$URL.'")">link</a></p>';
}

<script src="java.js"></script>
```

**java.js**

```
function test(para){
    alert(para);
        alert("Para"); 
    }
```

Calling the function without a variable works.
test() outputs two alerts:

```
Undefined
Para
```

Whenever I try to pass a variable, the function does not get called at all. No alert or anything else.

Comment: because you are creating an attribute like `onclick="test("somevalue")"` as you can see the attribute value is not properly enclosed

Comment: Then how would it be properly enclosed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
echo '<p><a href="'.$temp2a[$i].'" onClick="test(\''.$URL.'\')">link</a></p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote Replace your code, It seems mistake of single quotes balance.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($temp2a); $i++) {
 $URL = "xyz.php?eingabe=".$temp2a[$i]."&eingabe2=".$datei;
 echo '<p><a href="'.$temp2a[$i].'" onClick="test(\"'.$URL.'\")">link</a>   
 </p>';
}
```

Comment: Using that code I get an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\xyz.php on line 3